# Regular expression in java for matching string not enclosed in single quote

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing my scripts for wrong strings and have an array list with strings that shouldn't occur in my lines of code.

But some strings should pass when they are not exactly the string.

Examples:

list contains "FOO" and "BAR"

textlines:

```
This is foo
and this is BAR
but not 'foo'
and not 'BAR'
but also not FOO_BAR
but we want FOO%TEXT
and also bar.text
```

result

```
This is foo
and this is BAR
but we want FOO%TEXT
and also bar.text
```

I've tried a view examples I found online and on stackoverflow but these didn't work for me, they don't filter the quoted ones.

```
String pattern = ".*\\"+strTables[i]+"\\b.*[^(\\w|')]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println (strTables[i] + ": " + line);
    break;
}
```

Comment: The backslash is what I found online as a possible solution, but it is not the solution
the pattern you mention I don't want a word or a single quote after the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\b` (word boundary) before and after the word, to match a whole word.

Then, a look-behind like `(?<!')` at the beginning of the pattern to denote “*not preceded by a single quote*” and a look-ahead like `(?!')` at the end of the pattern to denote “*not followed by a single quote*”.

Putting it together makes

```java
String pattern = "(?<!')\\b" + strTables[i] + "\\b(?!')";
```